# stasmodels SARIMAX predictions

Tags: statsmodels

I'm trying to understand how to verify a ARIMAX model for > 1 step ahead using `statsmodels`.

My understanding is the `results.get_prediction(start=, dynamic=)` api does this but I'm having trouble getting my head around how it works. My training data is indexed by a localised DateTimeIndex (tz='Sydney\Australia') at 15T freq. I want to predict a full day for '2019-02-04 00:00:00+1100' using one-step-ahead prediction up to '2019-02-04 06:00:00+1100' the previous predicted endogenous values for the rest of the day.

Is the code below correct? It seems statsmodel converts the start to a TimeStamp and treats dynamic as a multiple of the freq, so this should start the simulation using 1 step ahead until 06:00 then use the previous predicted endogenous values. The results don't look great so I want to confirm it's a model issue rather than me having incorrect diagnosis.

```
dt = '2019-02-04'

predict = res.get_prediction(start='2019-02-04 00:00:00+11:00')     
predict_dy = res.get_prediction(start='2019-02-04 00:00:00+11:00', dynamic=4*6)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)) ax = fig.gca()

y_train[dt].plot(ax=ax, style='o', label='Observed')     
predict.predicted_mean[dt].plot(ax=ax, style='r--', label='One-step-ahead forecast')
predict_dy.predicted_mean[dt].plot(ax=ax, style='g', label='Dynamic forecast')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems statsmodel converts the start to a TimeStamp

Yes, if you give it a string value, then it will attempt to map it to an index in your dataset (like a timestamp).

> and treats dynamic as a multiple of the freq

But this is not correct. `dynamic` is an integer offset to `start`. So if `dynamic=0`, that means that dynamic prediction begins at `start`, whereas if `dynamic=1`, that means that dynamic prediction begins at `start+1`.

It's not quite clear to me what's going on in your example (or what you think is not great about the predictions you generated), so here is a description of how `dynamic` works that may help:

---

Here's an example that may help explain how things work. A couple of key points for this exercise will be:

- I set all elements of `endog` to be equal to 1
- This is an AR(1) model with parameter 0.5. That means that if we know y_t, then the prediction of y_t+1 is equal to 0.5 * y_t.

Now, the example code is:

```
ix = pd.date_range(start='2018-12-01', end='2019-01-31', freq='D')
endog = pd.Series(np.ones(len(ix)), index=ix)
mod = sm.tsa.SARIMAX(endog, order=(1, 0, 0), concentrate_scale=True)
res = mod.smooth([0.5])

p1 = res.predict(start='January 1, 2019', end='January 5, 2019').rename('d=False')
p2 = res.predict(start='January 1, 2019', end='January 5, 2019', dynamic=0).rename('d=0')
p3 = res.predict(start='January 1, 2019', end='January 5, 2019', dynamic=1).rename('d=2')

print(pd.concat([p1, p2, p3], axis=1))
```

this gives:

```
            d=False      d=0     d=2
2019-01-01      0.5  0.50000  0.5000
2019-01-02      0.5  0.25000  0.5000
2019-01-03      0.5  0.12500  0.2500
2019-01-04      0.5  0.06250  0.1250
2019-01-05      0.5  0.03125  0.0625
```

The first column (d=False) is the default case, where `dynamic=False`. Here, all predictions are one-step-ahead predictions. Since I set every element of `endog` to 1 and we have an AR(1) model with parameter 0.5, all one-step-ahead predictions will be equal to 0.5 * 1 = 0.5.

In the second column (d=0), we specify that `dynamic=0` so that dynamic prediction begins at the first prediction. This means that we do not use any `endog` data past `start - 1` in forming our predictions, which in this case means we do not use any data past December 31, 2018 in making predictions. The first prediction will be equal to 0.5 times the observation on December 31, 2018, i.e. 0.5 * 1 = 0.5. Each subsequent prediction will be equal to 0.5 * the previous prediction, so the second prediction is 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25, etc.

The third column (d=1) is like the second column, except that here `dynamic=1` so that dynamic prediction begins at the second prediction. This means we do not use any `endog` data past `start` (i.e. past January 1, 2019).

Comment: Thanks, but when you say start+1 what does that mean exactly when the data has 15T sample rate. Is +1 sample regardless of the sample rate? Specically is start='2019-02-04 00:00:00+11:00', dynamic=4*6 for 15T sample rate data equals to '2019-02-04 06:00:00+11:00'?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. It's +1 regardless of the frequency of your data, so yes, if you set `start='2019-02-04 00:00:00+11:00', dynamic=4*6` for 15T frequency, then the output will give one-step-ahead predictions through the period '2019-02-04 06:00:00+11:00' and then multi-step-ahead predictions for each forecast period after that.

Comment: PS When you say "It's not quite clear to me ... what you think is not great about the predictions you generated". I'm trying to create a model which can forecast ~3hours into the future as accurately as possible (conditioned on exog). The 1 step forecast (r--) is ok but of no use, the dynamic forecast (g) starts to diverge after about an hour which is why I don't feel it's a good model.